# How do I color flagged rows in an excel file exported from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I am cleaning some data on an excel sheet using pandas dataframes, and I have a list of flagged indices. Is there a way to color these specific rows red or yellow in pandas itself before exporting?

The flagged indices are is a list: [30556, 30981, 55893... etc]

I'm not sure what to try here as I'm new to Data Analysis with Python, only done a beginners course on EdX, so any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word you wanted to Google for was "styling".
Copious documentation is available.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Briefly excerpting from that,
one can define a styler

```
def make_pretty(styler):
    styler.background_gradient(axis=None, vmin=1, vmax=5, cmap="YlGnBu")
    return styler
```

and use it to e.g. map increasing values
to background colors that are increasingly blue.
Many additional [styling methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/style.html) are provided.

```
weather_df.loc[start:end].style.pipe(make_pretty)
```

[image: rain values]